# SQL Trigger past paper

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

i'm going through an old past paper on Database server management for my exam tomorrow and can't for the life of me answer it. Could anyone give me concise answer or at least point me in the right direction? Any help is greatly appreciated!

b) Audit data is often captured by the use of database triggers. 
(i) What would happen when the trigger is fired? 
(ii)    Discuss how this can affect normal database operations.
(6 marks)

```
Command (as user SYS):
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit-table-DEPT AFTER
  2  INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON DEPT FOR EACH ROW
  3  declare
  4  audit_data DEPT$audit%ROWTYPE;
  5  begin
  6      if inserting then audit_data.change_type := 'I';
  7      elsif updating then audit_data.change_type :='U';
  8      else audit_data.change_type := 'D';
  9      end if;
 10
 11      audit_data.changed_by := user;
 12      audit_data.changed_time := sysdate;
 13
 14      case audit_data.change_type
 15      when 'I' then
 16         audit_data.DEPTNO := :new.DEPTNO;
 17         audit_data.DNAME := :new.DNAME;
 18         audit_data.LOC := :new.LOC;
 19      else
 20         audit_data.DEPTNO := :old.DEPTNO;
 21         audit_data.DNAME := :old.DNAME;
 22         audit_data.LOC := :old.LOC;
 23      end case;
 24
 25      insert into DEPT$audit values audit_data;
 26  end;
 27  /
Trigger created.
```

Comment: Can you clarify what part of the question you don't understand?  Do you not understand triggers in general?  Do you not know the trigger syntax?  Are you unable to discern what effect this trigger in particular has?

Comment: I understand that the trigger fires on an insert, update or delete on the table DEPT. If inserting into the table then it does something, if it updates it does something else, if something is deleted something else, but i cannot work out what it is doing. From what i can gather if inserting it uses the character I to change some data (when 'I' then
          audit_data.DEPTNO := :new.DEPTNO;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigger is inserting a new row into an audit table every time something is inserted into, deleted from, or updated in the `DATA` table.

line 4 declares a new variable `audit_data`, which is a `%ROWTYPE` variable, meaning it will mimic a row in a database table, rather than holding just a single value the way an `INT` or `DOUBLE` would.

lines 6-9 set the value of `audit_data`'s `change_type` column.  If the trigger was called because we're inserting a row into `DATA`, then `change_type` is set to the value `I`.  If we're updating `DATA`, `change_type` is set to `U`.  Otherwise, we're deleting from `DATA`, and `change_type` is set to `D`.

Lines 11 & 12 set two more columns in `audit_data`.  The `changed_by` field is set equal to the user who is performing this insert/update/delete, and `change_time` is set equal to the current time.

Lines 14-23 then set the final three fields of `audit_data`: `DEPTNO`, `DNAME`, and `LOC`.  These fields have corresponding fields in the original `DATA` table.  If we are inserting a new row into `DATA` (we've previously set `change_type` to I), then the values of our new `audit_data` fields will be the new values inserted into `DATA`.  If we're either updating or deleting rows in `DATA`, we set the values of the new `audit_data` fields to instead be the old pre-update/pre-delete values from `DATA`.

Finally, Line 25 performs the actual insert into the audit table, inserting a row with all of the `audit_data` values we just got finished setting.

Comment: Thanks! For the second part of the question would it have an adverse affect on the speed/storage of the database due to the fact that whenever anything is inserted, updated or deleted then memory and processing power must be allocated to carry out the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

When the operation is an `INSERT`, the trigger takes the values of **the newly inserted** records and stores them in `DEPT$audit`.

When it's NOT AN INSERT (i.e. the operation is `UPDATE` or `DELETE`), then the trigger takes **the old values** (the old/current values from the updated/deleted rows) and again stores them in `DEPT$audit`.

This is done for history/auditing purposes apparently.